# name of string as a pointer to its first character

Tags: c++

Given

```
string name="avinash";  
cout<<&name;
```

If `name` is a pointer to a then how are we using address on a pointer?

Answer (score 7):

`name` is not a pointer, it's the `std::string` itself. So `&name` is the address of that string, which means that this code will print out a number.

Even if it were a pointer, using `operator &` on it would be perfectly legal: it would return the address of the pointer variable in memory (another, different, number).

If you want a pointer to the first character inside `name`, then use `name.c_str()` to get a C-style null-terminated string (which is actually a pointer to the first character of a string), or `name.data()` which returns a pointer to the string but doesn't guarantee that it will be null-terminated.

Comment: Also: Attempting to alter the C-style string will result in undefined behaviour (C++03 21.3.6/2 & 17.4.3.8)

Answer (score 3):

`name` is not a pointer, name is a `std::string` object. `&name`, which **is** a pointer, is the address of that object.

Answer (score 2):

1. `name` is not a pointer, it is an object of type `std::string`. `&name` gives you the address of that object.
2. To obtain a (const-)pointer to the first character of the string, use `name.c_str()`.
3. Pointers have addresses too!

   ```
   int i = 5;
   int *j = &i;
   int **k = &j;
   ```

   This is useful if you want to pass a pointer to a function that has to manipulate that pointer (for instance by allocating memory):

   ```
   void allocate_string(std::string **foo) {
       *foo = new std::string();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Hi string class have c_str() method. 
Use `const char* ptr = name.c_str();`